# How to display any video using phonon + python + qt in raspberry pi

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt4, phonon

I have raspberry pi3. I want to display any type of video using phonon+qt+python. I don't want to use c++ in QT. I had tried using following code, but it is giving error like: No module named phonon. I already install phonon using sudo apt-get install phonon, but still it is giving error like that. Any one know how to solve that or is there any other way to display video using python + qt or is there any other way to install phonon?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import PyQt4.phonon 

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.media = phonon.MediaObject(self)
        self.media.stateChanged.connect(self.handleStateChanged)
        self.video = phonon.VideoWidget(self)
        self.video.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.audio = phonon.AudioOutput(phonon.VideoCategory, self)
        phonon.createPath(self.media, self.audio)
        phonon.createPath(self.media, self.video)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Choose File', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.list.addItems(phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableMimeTypes())
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.video, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.media.state() == phonon.PlayingState:
            self.media.stop()
        else:
            path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, self.button.text())
            if path:
                self.media.setCurrentSource(phonon.MediaSource(path))
                self.media.play()

    def handleStateChanged(self, newstate, oldstate):
        if newstate == phonon.PlayingState:
            self.button.setText('Stop')
        elif (newstate != phonon.LoadingState and
              newstate != phonon.BufferingState):
            self.button.setText('Choose File')
            if newstate == phonon.ErrorState:
                source = self.media.currentSource().fileName()
                print ('ERROR: could not play:', source.toLocal8Bit().data())
                print ('  %s' % self.media.errorString().toLocal8Bit().data())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('phonon Player')
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You must install phonon for pyqt with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4-phonon
```

In addition you must correct certain imports and part of your code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.media = Phonon.MediaObject(self)
        self.video = Phonon.VideoWidget(self)
        self.video.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.audio = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.audio)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.video)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Choose File', self)

        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.list.addItems(Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableMimeTypes())
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.video, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)

        self.media.stateChanged.connect(self.handleStateChanged)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.media.state() == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.media.stop()
        else:
            path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, self.button.text())
            if path:
                self.media.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(path))
                self.media.play()

    def handleStateChanged(self, newstate, oldstate):
        if newstate == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.button.setText('Stop')
        elif newstate != Phonon.LoadingState and newstate != Phonon.BufferingState:
            self.button.setText('Choose File')
            if newstate == Phonon.ErrorState:
                source = self.media.currentSource().fileName()
                print('ERROR: could not play:', source.toLocal8Bit().data())
                print('  %s' % self.media.errorString().toLocal8Bit().data())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('phonon Player')
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Have u any working swf file?plz attach it. Because i try this example and run it but it is showing blank black screen. So i want to check is problem in my swf file or i m getting problem in this script running.